# Mysql doesn't want to give access to jdbc. What can I do?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-administration

I try to connect to newly created database but with no success. Tried all prescribtions from the net. Any ideas?

[image: Can't connect]
[image: But database and privileges are ok]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had two mysqls running. Check it in your administrative tools, may be this may help you...